# How to prevent user from deleting item by pressing "backspace"?

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu, combobox, backspace

Users will usually expand the `ComboBox`, pick the desired option and the `ComboBox` will hide other options. Now user can delete the chosen option by pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> button. May I know how to prevent it?

Comment: Can't you just capture the event (Keypress/Keydown) and then avoid it being executed in the case of backspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be avoided by handling the PreviewKeyDown event and marking any use of the backspace key as handled

```
void OnComboPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { 
  if (e.Key == Key.Back) { 
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set its DropDownStyle to DropDownList if you don't want it to be editable at all.